# p Element Expands its Container Against Upwards

Tags: html, css, display

- I have 3 div elements which their **display** property is set to **inline-block;** inside a *container* with properties 
  **width: 80%;** || **margin: auto;** || **text-align: center;**
- There is an **img** and a **p** element inside the 3 divs.
- When the text in the p elements gets into the second line, **it is expanding against upward and it's breaking the alignment between images and other p elements.**

Here is the code and its result: https://jsfiddle.net/yrvd51f6/11/

I leave it here as a code block also.

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.boxContent {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}

.boxContent img {
  width: 20%;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <h1>Who We Are?</h1>

  <!-- FIRST BOX ------------------------------------->
  <div class="boxContent">
    <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/orange-circle-png-3.png">
    <p>Description Text</p>
  </div>
  <!-- SECOND BOX ------------------------------------->
  <div class="boxContent">
    <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/orange-circle-png-3.png">
    <p>If this text gets in to second line, align will be broken. Why? I don't understand this CSS sometimes. If this text gets in to second line and more, it heighthens upwards. But I didn't set a height value, shouldn't it heighthen downwards and images
      stay aligned? . Why this is happening? I don't understand this CSS sometimes.</p>
  </div>

  <!-- THIRD BOX ------------------------------------->
  <div class="boxContent">
    <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/orange-circle-png-3.png">
    <p>Description Text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `vertical-align` property. Set it to `top` in the `boxContent` class, and it should be aligned to the top of its parent. The default value for this property is, in case of inline elements, `baseline`, which aligns according to the baseline of the parent element, and that's why by default it is in the bottom.

Check MDN for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#Values_(for_inline_elements)

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.boxContent {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 30%;
}

.boxContent img {
  width: 20%;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <h1>Who We Are?</h1>

  <!-- FIRST BOX ------------------------------------->
  <div class="boxContent">
    <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/orange-circle-png-3.png">
    <p>Description Text</p>
  </div>

  <!-- SECOND BOX ------------------------------------->
  <div class="boxContent">
    <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/orange-circle-png-3.png">
    <p>If this text gets into the second line, align will be broken. Why? I don't understand this CSS sometimes. If this text gets into the second line and more, it heightens upwards. But I didn't set a height value, shouldn't it heighten downwards and images
      stay aligned? . Why this is happening? I don't understand this CSS sometimes.</p>
  </div>

  <!-- THIRD BOX ------------------------------------->
  <div class="boxContent">
    <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/orange-circle-png-3.png">
    <p>Description Text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much you are the best. I have been trying to solve this problem like 2 hours since I am an absolute beginner, you taught me something new today! Really, many thanks!